# How to remove Dom4j 1.6.1 jar from classpath and add the same jar depedency in MANIFEST.MF file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

I have my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
                     <exclusion>
                     <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>
```

i have deleted the dom4j 1.6.1 jar from class path , when i build again maven tries to download and add it to class path .how to properly avoid adding that jar to classpath and add through only MANIFEST.MF file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added the dependency with the **scope provided** and it removed my exception..

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
                         <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```